# Scala: how to use google/facebook credentials to provide access control for my application via openID on Heroku

Tags: scala, heroku, openid, credentials, scalatra

I'm writing a hobby project with Scala on Heroku. Currently I have my own authentication mechanism which uses http basic auth. I'd like to be able to use people's existing credentials from e.g. google or facebook instead. I know that for Ruby there's omniauth which should do the trick. Is there an equivalent solution for Scala which works on Heroku? I'm using Scalatra as the web stack.

Answer (score 1):

Never used myself but you probably would like to take a look at [socialauth](https://code.google.com/p/socialauth/) library.

Comment: Thanks! A bit too fancy for my purposes though, I'm going with openid4java instead.

Answer (score 0):

Hacked together something minimal with [openid4java](https://code.google.com/p/openid4java/) now. Documentation is not great, but I've managed to log in with my google account.

Here's the code I use from my servlet:

```
package auth

import org.openid4java.discovery.Identifier
import org.openid4java.discovery.DiscoveryInformation
import org.openid4java.message.ax.FetchRequest
import org.openid4java.message.ax.FetchResponse
import org.openid4java.message.ax.AxMessage
import org.openid4java.message._
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse
import java.util.List
import org.openid4java.consumer.{VerificationResult, ConsumerManager}

case class AuthenticatedUser(identifier: Identifier, email: Option[String])

class OpenIdConsumer {
  val manager: ConsumerManager = new ConsumerManager

  def authenticateGoogleUser(request: HttpServletRequest, response: HttpServletResponse) {
    val googleOpenIdRequestString = "https://www.google.com/accounts/o8/id"
    val returnToUrl = request.getScheme() + "://" + request.getServerName() + ":" + request.getServerPort() + "/openid"
    authRequest(googleOpenIdRequestString, returnToUrl, request, response)
  }

  def authRequest(userSuppliedString: String, returnToUrl: String, httpReq: HttpServletRequest, httpResp: HttpServletResponse) {
    val discoveries = manager.discover(userSuppliedString)
    val discovered = manager.associate(discoveries)
    httpReq.getSession.setAttribute("openid-disc", discovered)
    val authReq = manager.authenticate(discovered, returnToUrl)
    val fetch = FetchRequest.createFetchRequest
    fetch.addAttribute("email", "http://schema.openid.net/contact/email", true)
    authReq.addExtension(fetch)
    httpResp.sendRedirect(authReq.getDestinationUrl(true))
  }

  def verifyResponse(httpReq: HttpServletRequest): Either[String, AuthenticatedUser] = {
    try {
      doVerifyResponse(httpReq)
    }
    catch {
      case e: Exception => {
        e.printStackTrace
        Left(e.getMessage)
      }
    }
  }

  private def doVerifyResponse(httpReq: HttpServletRequest): Either[String, AuthenticatedUser] = {
    val response: ParameterList = new ParameterList(httpReq.getParameterMap)
    val discovered: DiscoveryInformation = httpReq.getSession.getAttribute("openid-disc").asInstanceOf[DiscoveryInformation]
    val receivingURL: StringBuffer = httpReq.getRequestURL
    val queryString: String = httpReq.getQueryString
    if (queryString != null && queryString.length > 0) receivingURL.append("?").append(httpReq.getQueryString)
    val verification: VerificationResult = manager.verify(receivingURL.toString, response, discovered)
    val verified: Identifier = verification.getVerifiedId
    if (verified != null) {
      val authSuccess: AuthSuccess = verification.getAuthResponse.asInstanceOf[AuthSuccess]
      if (authSuccess.hasExtension(AxMessage.OPENID_NS_AX)) {
        val fetchResp: FetchResponse = authSuccess.getExtension(AxMessage.OPENID_NS_AX).asInstanceOf[FetchResponse]
        val emails: List[_] = fetchResp.getAttributeValues("email")
        val email: String = emails.get(0).asInstanceOf[String]
        return Right(AuthenticatedUser(verified, Some(email)))
      }
      return Right(AuthenticatedUser(verified, None))
    }
    Left("Not authenticated")
  }
}
```

And my servlet now contains these entry-points to test it:

```
  val consumer = new OpenIdConsumer
  ...

  get("/authenticate") {
    consumer.authenticateGoogleUser(request, response)
  }


  get("/openid") {
    val retval = consumer.verifyResponse(request)
    println("retval: " + retval)
    <html>
      <body>
        <h1>Openid return page</h1>
      </body>
    </html>
  }
```